# Where to see list of currently deprecated API of Apple?

Tags: ios, api, deprecated

I know that there are some deprecated APIs like `paymentWithProductIdentifier`(SKPayment). I'm trying to get a compilation. Is there a place i could go to to see them all? I tried searching on the net and I couldn't find one. Maybe Apple has a page that i don't know of? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide any separate listing of deprecated APIs, however they do release a page covering all the differences they make in each release. This [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html) covers all such change logs.

And API level change log can be found on this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014455) but you need to go through each framework to find the deprecated APIs. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apple documents their deprecations in the change logs of every iOS/Mac release. In addition to that every deprecated class, method or function is marked as deprecated by crossing it out in their API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008244-SW1

On each page for each iOS version will be a link to "API Diffs".

I guess it depends on how far you want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [StoreKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008300), if you view each documentation you'll see the deprecated method, those are crossed. Hope this helps.. :)

This might be helpful, see [StoreKit Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS81APIDiffs/modules/StoreKit.html)